# Connectivity period of oracle JDBC connection or session

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ojdbc

While loading up my java spring application , i am making a jdbc connection using url, username and password through drivermanagerDatasource and it was able to connect to jdbc successfully .

Consider a scenario:  The application was processing a file for a period of 10 AM - 11 AM.

Now suppose if i change the oracle password at 10:30 AM .

Q1. What will happen to the application? will it throw error?

Q2. What will happen to the connection object? whats its validity period?

Q3. before inserting or updating a single record into DB , does every time the application checks the username and password ?

Would be great help if anyone answer this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The password is only checked at login time. You'll be fine until your connection dies and you try to re-establish the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is this period configurable? and also could you please tell whether the connection re establishing process is manual or ojdbc driver do for us

Comment: you need to split your question into multiple questions - timeouts/connection duration has nothing to do with password validation